# Trying to connect to AWS instance .. Ping fails while Telnet/ SSH works fine

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, couchbase, socketexception

I have two AWS instances running COUCHBASE .. and ,,,, Trying to connect to AWS instance .. Ping fails while Telnet/ SSH works fine.

Can connect to it using `http://xscx:8091`

While doing it via java api I get errors like

`2013-10-23 19:59:06.534 WARN com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:                           Closing, and reopening {QA sa=172.31.12.165/172.31.12.165:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=1, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=Cmd: 1 Opaque: 1 Key: 0 Cas: 0 Exp: 0 Flags: 0 Data Length: 1570, toWrite=0, interested=0}, attempt 3.`

 `2013-10-23 19:59:06.544 INFO com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@60051f44`

```
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:423)
at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:261)
at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection.run(CouchbaseConnection.java:288)
```

``` 2013-10-23 19:59:06.545 WARN com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=172.31.5.85/172.31.5.85:11210, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}, attempt 3.``
ava.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for operation ```

!http://i40.tinypic.com/2qun6us.png

Answer (score 2):

You say

> Ping fails while Telnet/ SSH works fine

Ping uses ICMP while Telnet and SSH use TCP/IP. These are different protocols and are blocked differently at firewalls.  Many firewall operators explicitly block ICMP to mitigate denial of service attacks, so this is not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open ports explicitly (If windows you need to open in ports in Windows Firewall). By default AWS ports will be closed (open local)

Comment: @user2601010: My experience was, I had to open them in windows firewall as well as AWS Console--> Security groups. Only one (or) two ports (like RDP were open)

Comment: chk the image ... I opened most inbound outbound ports in local machine`s firewall .. still can`t ping

Comment: I put "ALL TCP" PORT to open for both AWS-Security Group and My Local Computer but still getting the same error ...